# Woher stammt „runkeln“ im Sinne von "schlafen"?

Tags: etymology

Als ich mich neulich mit einem Bekannten unterhielt, verwendete ich den Satz „Ich gehe jetzt **runkeln**“, was dieser jedoch nicht verstand. Ich verwende das Wort eigentlich schon immer als Synonym für **schlafen**.

Meine Recherchen nach dem Ursprung blieben erfolglos, da im Internet hauptsächlich das Wort mit Runkelrüben verbunden wird. Gefühlsmäßig würde ich es jedoch eher vom lautmalerischen Schnarchen ableiten.

Ich selber habe es aus dem Alltagswortschatz meiner Verwandten übernommen, die aus dem sächsischen Sprachraum stammen, vermutlich ist der Ursprung dort zu finden.

Woher stammt denn jetzt genau dieses Verb und wie ist es entstanden?

Comment: Als langjähriger, aber nicht-gebürtiger Sachse kann ich schonmal keine allgemeine Verbreitung des Wortes in Sachsen attestieren.

Comment: Ich kenne nur "ratzen" als lautmalerischen Ausdruck für "schlafen", "runkeln" habe ich noch nie gehört (Raum Frankfurt/Main).

Comment: Suchst Du die sprachliche Herkunft, also etwa mittelhochdeutsch soundso, indogermanisch trallala, oder eine präzisere räumliche Herkunft?

Comment: Also mich hätte eher die räumliche Herkunft interessiert. Wenn der Begriff nun wirklich so unbekannt ist, reduziere ich das aber vielleicht lieber doch auf die simple Frage: Kennt jemand den Begriff in seinem Sprachschatz? Darüber müsste sich die Herkunft doch auch grob ableiten lassen.

Comment: Es ist ziemlich weit hergeholt, aber vielleicht ein Ansatz: Eines der vielen Territorien des Heiligen Römischen Reichs Deutscher Nation war das [Fürstentum Wied](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrstentum_Wied), mit [Runkel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runkel) und Dierdorf als Zentren. Einer der Fürsten, [Hans Ernst zu Wied-Runkel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Ernst_zu_Wied-Runkel) war Mitglied der [Fruchtbringenden Gesellschaft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruchtbringende_Gesellschaft), einer Sprachakademie. Dort erhielt er als Motto "befördert den Schlaf".

Comment: In Bayern ist mir das Wörtchen auch noch nie begegnet.

Comment: Könnte es auch eine familieninterne Neuschöpfung sein? (Also  von  deinem Urahn erfunden und von seinen Nachkommen weiter benutzt)

Answer (score 10):

Ich vermute, dass runkeln eine Variante ist von "runken", das im *Deutsches Wörterbuch der Brüder Grimm* erwähnt wird:

> RUNKEN, *verb. nd.* schnarchen, *nld.* ronken. *auch schweiz.*

(nld. = Niederländisch) Ich kann bestätigen, das "[ronken](http://vandale.nl/opzoeken?pattern=ronken&lang=nn)" in Flandern noch benutzt wird; es bezieht sich vor allem auf die Schnarch*geräusche*.

Ich habe nicht gefunden ob "runkeln" vielleicht aus einer Kombination von "runken" und "rumpeln" (ein dumpfes Geräusch verursachen) entstanden sein könnte.

In den folgenden Nachschlagewerken habe ich "runken" und "runkeln" vergeblich gesucht:

- Duden. Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache in 10 Bänden. (Dudenverlag, 1999).
- KLUGE: Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache. 25. Aufl. (De Gruyter, 2011).
- Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen. 2. Aufl., durchg. & ergänzt von Wolfgang Pfeiffer. (Akademie Verlag, 1993).

Comment: Ich bin Niederländer und fand es auch *ronken* (schnarchen) ähnlich. Wird wenigstens im Süden auch noch benutzt, aber wahrscheinlich kennen die anderen "Holländer" das auch.